# `GROUP BY` alone

Tags: sql, group-by

In some SQL code I have, there is a simple part:

```
(SELECT
      t1.col1,
      ...,
      t1.coln
   FROM
      (SELECT
            t2.col1, ..., t2.coln
         FROM
            t2location
      ) t1

   GROUP BY
         t1.col1,
         ...,
         t1.coln
) t0
```

where I thought "wow what is this `GROUP BY` doing here, it only sorts it". So I removed it but then it changes the resulting table drastically.

This table, `t0` is subsequently left outer joined with another table with a similar group by (with less data, but same columns).

My question is:

> What is the `GROUP BY` doing that changes the data?

The data set is very large and I cannot pinpoint what is going on the with the code exactly.

Comment: It's doing an inherent `DISTINCT`.  If you remove the `GROUP BY (All Columns)` and add `SELECT DISTINCT ...` you should get the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confusing `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`. GROUP BY aggregates your data so is usually used with aggregate functions such as SUM or AVERAGE. GROUP BY works by selecting disctict values in a particular column and grouping them together. While GROUP BY may indeed sort data it is not guaranteed. ORDER BY is used soley for sorting.

Comment: To answer the question: a GROUP BY does not change data. It just aggregates some things and display's it in the way you ask it to. No data will be changed.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Any time you use only a SELECT statement you are not modifying the actual data in a table. SELECT only retrieves data.

Answer (score 2):

It is *basically* doing a `SELECT DISTINCT t1.col, ..., t1.coln`:

For example:

```
  col1   |  col2  |  col3
---------|--------|------
  some   | thing  | cool
  some   | thing  | cool
  some   | thing  | cool
  some   | thing  | else
   wow   | thats  | cool
```

Your query without the `GROUP BY` would return five rows.  *With* the `GROUP BY` would return three rows: something that looks like row 1, and row 4 and 5